# make a Asynchronous request with Swiftyjson

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, asynchronous, swifty-json

I have 3 of following methods with different names. However at the moment when they are being executed they seem to block the UI. I guess this is do to im making a Synchronous request, so how can i make this a Asynchronous request?

```
func getPopular(url: NSString) {

    let popularUrl = NSURL(string: url as String)
    var popularRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: popularUrl!)
    var popularData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(popularRequest, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

    let jsonArray = JSON(data: popularData!)
    if jsonArray.count < numberOfRecordsPerAPICall {
        popularCount = 0
        self.tableVIew.tableFooterView = nil
    } else {
        popularCount = jsonArray.count
        self.tableVIew.tableFooterView = footerView
    }
    for (key: String, subJson: JSON) in jsonArray {

        var httpUrl = subJson["image_url"].stringValue
        let url = NSURL(string: httpUrl)
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        // Create an object and parse your JSON one by one to append it to your array
        var newNewsObject = News(id: subJson["id"].intValue, title: subJson["title"].stringValue, link: subJson["url"].stringValue, imageLink: UIImage(data: data!)!, summary: subJson["news_text"].stringValue, date: getDate(subJson["date"].stringValue))





        popularArray.append(newNewsObject)
    }
```

Comment: You can use multi-threading if you don't want the UI blocked.

Comment: Is that better than a asyncronous request?

Comment: use `sendAsynchronousRequest` instead of `sendSynchronousRequest`

Comment: and then what should queue and completionHandler be set to? in sendAsyncrhonous?